# How to use isValidating in multiple SWR calls in the same component

Tags: reactjs, swr

Question: How do I use `isValidating` in two separate API calls inside of one component?

I have a dashboard component that shows open and completed orders. I have to call two different endpoints (one for getting the open orders and one for getting the completed orders). I would like to use `isValidating` to check the state of both API responses and show a loading animation accordingly.

```
   //Order Dashboard Component
import Callout from '../components/cards/Callout';

function OrdersDashboard() {
    const ordersEndpoint = `${BASE_URL}/orders`;
    const openOrdersEndpoint = `${ordersEndpoint}&completed=false`;
    const completedOrdersEndpoint = `${orderEndpoint}&completed=true`;

    //Endpoint #1
    const {
        data: openOrders,
        error: openOrdersError,
        isValidating,
    } = useSWR([openOrdersEndpoint, BASE_URL], ([url, audience]) =>
        fetchData(url, audience)
    );

    //Endpoint #2
    const {
        data: completedOrders,
        error: completedOrdersError,
        isValidating,
    } = useSWR([completedOrdersEndpoint, BASE_URL], ([url, audience]) =>
        fetchData(url, audience)
    );

    if (completedOrdersError || openOrdersError) {
        return <div>Error</div>;
    }

    if (!completedOrders && !openOrders) {
        return <div>Loading...</div>;
    }

    return (
        <>
            <h1>Orders Dashboard</h1>
            <section id='openOrders' className='section'>
                {!openOrders || !openOrders.length ? (
                    <>
                        <h2>Open Orders</h2>
                        <Callout
                            message='No Open Orders'
                            isValidating={isValidating}
                        />
                    </>
                ) : (
                    <DataTable columns={columns} data={openOrders} />
                )}
            </section>

            <section id='completedOrders' className='section'>
                {!completedOrders || !completedOrders.length ? (
                    <>
                        <h2>Completed Orders </h2>
                        <Callout
                            message='No Completed Orders'
                            isValidating={isValidating}
                        />
                    </>
                ) : (
                    <DataTable columns={columns} data={completedOrders} />
                )}
            </section>
        </>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
//Endpoint #1
    const {
        data: openOrders,
        error: openOrdersError,
        isValidating: validatePending
    } = useSWR([openOrdersEndpoint, BASE_URL], ([url, audience]) =>
        fetchData(url, audience)
    );

    //Endpoint #2
    const {
        data: completedOrders,
        error: completedOrdersError,
        isValidating: validateCompleted
    } = useSWR([completedOrdersEndpoint, BASE_URL], ([url, audience]) =>
        fetchData(url, audience)
    );
```